# Putting item in static bundle make app crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a class `var.java` that has bundle declared as static   `public static Bundle bresult;`.

In activity fragment, if I want to put a string in that bundle `var.bresult.putString("h",String.valueOf(h));`, the app crash.

However, if i make a new bundle in the activity class and put the value in it, then make the static bundle equal to the new bundle, it works.

```
public class var {
    public  static  boolean u = true ;
    public static int ui = 0;
    public static Bundle bresult;

    Bundle bresult2 = new Bundle();

    bresult2.putString("h",String.valueOf(h));

    var.bresult = bresult2;
}
```

**Why is this happening? what causes the crash?**

This is the fragment code :

```java
public  class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
     private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
     public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_b, container, false);
final EditText etxh;     
final Button buDesign = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buDesign);
buDesign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            etxh = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            h = Double.valueOf(etxh.getText().toString());
            var.bresult.putString("h",String.valueOf(h));
        }
      });
     return rootView;
   }
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace

Comment: This isn´t enough code to give you an answer. You might want to add more of your code and include the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Your static variable doesn't have an instance because you didn't initialize it:

```
public static Bundle bresult;
```

has to become:

```
public static Bundle bresult = new Bundle();
```